# Open app on Widget click while having another pending intent

Tags: android, widget, android-pendingintent

The onUpdate method of my widget should do 2 things:

1. set an onClickListener that opens an Activity when I click the widget.
2. set an Alarmmanager that updates the textboxes on my widget every 10 seconds.

This is how my the method looks:

```
 @Override
public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, int[] appWidgetIds) {
    // There may be multiple widgets active, so update all of them
    final int N = appWidgetIds.length;
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {

        // Create an Intent to launch Activity
       Intent openApp = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
       openApp.putExtra("IntentId", 1);
       PendingIntent pendingAppIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 1, openApp, 0);
       RemoteViews views = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.hsvuhr_widget);
       views.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.rlmy, pendingAppIntent);

        Intent update = new Intent(context, UpdateService.class);
        update.putExtra("IntentId",2);
        PendingIntent pendingUpdateIntent = PendingIntent.getService(context, 2, update, 0);
        AlarmManager alarm = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        alarm.cancel(pendingUpdateIntent);
        long interval = 10000;
        alarm.setRepeating(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME, SystemClock.elapsedRealtime(),interval, pendingUpdateIntent);
    }
}
```

But in this code is a mistake. The onClickListener does not work. The Widget updates every 10 seconds, but I nothing opens when I click the widget.

Can anyone see my mistake?

EDIT: This is how I changed my code. Here is my AppWidgetProvider

```
 @Override
public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, int[] appWidgetIds) {

    // Create an Intent to launch Activity
    Intent openApp = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
    openApp.putExtra("IntentId", 1);
    PendingIntent pendingAppIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 1, openApp, 0);
    RemoteViews views = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.hsvuhr_widget);
    views.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.rlmy, pendingAppIntent);
    Intent update = new Intent(context, UpdateService.class);
    update.putExtra("IntentId",2);
    PendingIntent pendingUpdateIntent = PendingIntent.getService(context, 2, update, 0);
    AlarmManager alarm = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    alarm.cancel(pendingUpdateIntent);
    long interval = 5000;
    alarm.setRepeating(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME, SystemClock.elapsedRealtime(),interval, pendingUpdateIntent);
    appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetIds, views);
}
```

And here is my updateClass:

```
 @Override
protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {

    Context context = this;
    AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager = AppWidgetManager.getInstance(context);
    RemoteViews remoteViews = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.hsvuhr_widget);
    ComponentName thisWidget = new ComponentName(context,HSVUhrWidget.class);


    remoteViews.setTextViewText("stuff");

    appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(thisWidget, remoteViews);
}
```

So onUpdate will call my updateClass every 5 seconds. The update class will fire a appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(thisWidget, remoteViews); and after that, back in the AppWidgetProvider there will be another appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetIds, views).

Problem now: The widget updates correctly, but after the first update the onClickEvent does not fire. So i can open the app at first but after an update I can't anymore. Where is my mistake?

Answer (score 0):

At the end of the method call

```
appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetIds, remoteViews);
```